# Border under text but not through the text

Tags: css

I'm making a web design for my magazine. Right now, I'm trying to make something like the 1996 title you can see on the picture below. With a border going under the text, but a white background around the text. Anybody can help me to do this? :)

[image: Click here to see image.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="heading">
  <h1>Heading Title</h1>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.heading {
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:2px solid #d5d5d5;
}
.heading h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:36px;
  position:relative;
  top:18px;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0 12px;
}
div,h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jkhGx/)**