# Creating a Border through and also around text

Tags: html, css, border

How to I create a border that moves through text like this without covering up the text?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [border under text but not through text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332537/border-under-text-but-not-through-the-text) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HTML `fieldset` for this with `legend`. All CSS stuff here is fully optional.

Also `legend`'s `before` and `after` can be used to set space near its text. Note that this way you won't be overlapping your background.

Demo:

```css
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #4b94ec;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #848fa9;
}

legend {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

legend:before,
legend:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
}

fieldset div {
  color: #b53f56;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Reliable</legend>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
  <div>More text here</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I never knew about the fieldset/legend stuff... this is much better than the answer I provided.

Comment: @Axion I was just thinking that. Thanks @VadimOvchinnikov! One of the best things about SO is that, while you might be able to solve a problem, you might still learn a more elegant solution from someone else. Love it.

Comment: @sauntimo Nice to hear:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. The key thing to point out is the `.title` span which has `position: relative` and `top` set on it to move it upwards from where it would otherwise be in the flow, and a `background-color` to stop the border from going through the text.

```css
.container {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.title {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 35px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}

p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="title">Reliable</span>
    <p>More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the background color of the word "RELIABLE" to the same background color of the div. Then using a negative margin-top you can position the text so it sits along the top border. Below is a quick example I put together.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXWrbe

**HTML**

```
<div id="blah">
  <h4>RELIABLE</h4>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#blah {
  width: 180px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

#blah h4 {
  width: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
  color: blue;
}

#blah p {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also take a look at the flex properties and margins to reset things on place ....

```css
.mebox {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid turquoise;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border-top: none;
}

.mebox h4 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 -2.1em 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

h4:before,
h4:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  height: 1em;
  border-top: solid turquoise;
  border-radius: 0 1em;
  margin: auto 1em;
}

h4:before {
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mebox">
  <h4>RELIABLE</h4>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
</div>

<div class="mebox">
  <h4>RELIABLE</h4>
  <p>More Text Here More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
  <p>More Text Here</p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pwmmrd